# Program that asks user for numbers and outputs the sum and the amount of numbers entered

Tags: python, loops, count, while-loop, addition

I'm writing a program that asks the user for numbers until the input is "stop". The program should output how many numbers were entered and the sum of the numbers.

I have this code:

```
count = 1
numberstring = input("Please enter a number: ")
number = float(numberstring)
while number != "stop":
    numberString = input("Please enter another number: ")
    number1 = float(numberString)
    sum = number + number1
    count = count + 1
    print("The amount of numbers you entered was: " + str(count) + " and the sum of all these numbers together is: " + str(sum))
```

Everything works well the first time, but as soon as I enter another number, the addition will be incorrect. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than finding the sum of all the numbers, the code only calculates the sum of the first number the user entered and the latest number.

`sum` is set with the code `sum = number + number1`; but `number` is never updated - it's always the first number the user input. `number1`, on the other hand, is only the last number the user input. Thus, `sum` is always set to the sum of the first and last numbers.

Instead, add the latest number to `sum`, like so: `sum += number1` (with `sum` set to `0` before the loop).

There is another problem here:

```
    number1 = float(numberString)
```

This line will throw an error if `numberString` can't be converted to `float`. The loop condition checks to see if `numberString == 'stop'`, but this can never be true. If the user enters "stop", the program will instead raise a `ValueError`, since that string can't be converted. Therefore, the condition should be checked *before* converting the `numberString` to a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt = "Please enter a number: "
sum = 0
count = 0
while True:
    s = input(prompt)
    prompt = "Please enter another number: "
    if s.lower() == 'stop':
        break
    try:
        sum += float(s)
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Bad number.  Try again")
print("You entered %s numbers whose sum is %s." % (count, sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes numbers one by one and updates the total and count accordingly, and computes an average at the end. If a letter is encountered it subtracts 1 from the count, otherwise the average would be wrong. If 'done' is encountered, the loop is exited. The average is calculated outside the loop, as it just needs to be calculated once.

```
count = 0
total = 0
average = 0 
while True:
    numlist = input('Enter number\n')
    if numlist == 'done':
        break
    try:
        count = count + 1
        total = total + float(numlist)
    except:
        count = count - 1
        print('Enter a valid number')
        continue

average = float(total) / float(count)   
print('Count:', count)
print('Total:', total)
print('Avg:', average)
```

Answer (score -1):

Modified to stop/break if the input is empty.

```
count = 0
total = 0
average = 0 
while True:
    numlist = input('Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ')
    if numlist == '':
        break
    try:
        count = count + 1
        total = total + float(numlist)
    except:
        count = count - 1
        print('Enter a valid number')
        continue
average = float(total) / float(count) 
print('The sum is', total)
print('The average is', average)
```